# Paymentshield SOAP API

Tags: php, soap

Currently I am working on paymentshield  SOAP Api with PHP  to call CreateQuoteRequest Method

```
    //SoapClient::__getFunctions
[0] => ArrayOfCreateQuoteRequestResult CreateQuoteRequest(CreateQuoteRequest $parameters)
    [1] => SubmitApplicationResponse SubmitApplication(SubmitApplication $parameters)




///SoapClient::__getTypes
 [3] => struct AgencyCredentialsMessagePart {
 string Password;
 int SellerNumber;
}
    [4] => struct CredentialsMessagePart {
 guid SystemIntegratorId;
}
    [5] => struct GroupedAnswerDataMessagePart {
 ArrayOfSingleAnswerDataMessagePart AnswerDataMessages;
}
    [6] => struct AnswerDataMessagePart {
}
    [7] => struct ArrayOfSingleAnswerDataMessagePart {
 SingleAnswerDataMessagePart SingleAnswerDataMessagePart;
}
    [8] => struct SingleAnswerDataMessagePart {
 string Key;
 string Value;
}
    [9] => struct EmailCredentialsMessagePart {
 string Email;
 string Password;
}
    [10] => struct EmailCredentials {
 string Email;
}
    [11] => struct AgencyCredentials {
 int SellerNumber;
}
    [12] => struct CreateQuoteRequest {
 QuoteRequestInputMessage inputMessage;
}
    [13] => struct QuoteRequestInputMessage {
 ArrayOfAnswerDataMessagePart Answers;
 string BranchNumber;
 CallChannelTypes CallChannelType;
 CredentialsMessagePart Credentials;
 boolean IsIndicativeQuote;
 int LeadId;
 int ProductId;
 decimal SacrificeLevel;
}
    [14] => struct ArrayOfAnswerDataMessagePart {
 AnswerDataMessagePart AnswerDataMessagePart;
}
```

when I try to call soap fault return with message "Cannot create an abstract class."

Anyone who can work with paymentshield  Please help,
Thanks in Advance`

Comment: WSDL file which  I use   http://servicesuat.paymentshield.co.uk/Quotations/QuoteRequestService?singleWsdl

Comment: Can you post how `$SoapClient` variable is created and `CreateQuoteRequest` call? Thanks.